# Working on developing face detection in C++ with openCV & dlib, program is ready but how to compile including dlib and opencv in cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake, object-detection, dlib

[I am getting following error when I try to compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH5Ub.png)

In my example directory I have added my .cpp. ALso I have checked all .so files exist in the path.

If anyone have used openCV with dlib for C++ program , please let me know detailed steps.

I tried adding following to the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/opencv2")
set(OpenCV_LIBS "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so"
            "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so"
            "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so"
            "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgcodecs.so"
            "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so"
            "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so")

# Add your source files
add_executable(exp7 exp7.cpp)

# Include OpenCV headers
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Link OpenCV libraries
target_link_libraries(exp7 ${OpenCV_LIBS} dlib::dlib)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect error message to be in the **question post** as **text**, not linked as *image*. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] your question post accordingly. Also, make sure that the error message **corresponds** to the code (currently the error is about `mounth_detection_dlib` target, but your code doesn't contain it).